# PostSharp handle handled exceptions

Tags: exception, postsharp

There are many Try/Catch blocks in my app to catch exceptions. I would like to read such handled exceptions and log them to a file. Is it possible to read handled exceptions with PostSharp?

Answer (score 2):

no. PostSharp works by wrapping your methods in try/catch blocks of its own and then just rethrowing the exception. Any exceptions handled in your method would be an inner try/catch while postsharp would only have outer try/catch blocks. You would either 1) have to rethrow the exception or 2) Handle those exceptions using an aspect. Neither of which I recommend.

Comment: I thought that PostSharp will have some kind of code injection possibility.

Comment: @Tomas Not in the way you're thinking.

Comment: This is why I personally try to avoid writing try catch blocks. Hopefully you can refactor and centralize your error handling?

Comment: @Andre I agree. try/catch should only be used when specific exceptions can be dealt with and at the top most level of the interface (before going back to the caller) to rethrow generic exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this (!) is to have a method that you call within the catch that will log the parameters passed into the exception.  Simply pass the exception in and the logger will log the information.

```cs
[LogParameters(LogLevel.Error)]
private static void Error(Exception ex) { }

public class LogParameters : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExcutionArgs args) {
        for (int i=0; i<args.Arguments.Count; i++) {
            // Get argument from args.Arguments.GetArgument(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `OnEntry` method of a customized `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`, you can log the exception information by calling a method and passing in the exception.  The method doesn't need to actually DO anything, it just is a dummy for the aspect to wrap around and log the exception parameter.